# Pointers as parameters to functions

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a program here:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void f1(int* x){
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(x); i++) {
    cout<<x[i]<<endl;
  }
}

void f2(int* x) {
  cout<<x<<endl;
}

int main() {
 int a=3;
 int a1[3]={2,3,1};
 f1(a1);
 f2(a);    
}
```

The function f1 allows me to pass an array as the argument to function but does not allow an integer variable to be passed as an argument.

How is this justified?
Does this have anything with the fact that the pointer takes 8 bytes of memory while integer takes only 4?

I get the following error when I run the code:

```
invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'

argument of type 'int' is incompatible with parameter of type 'int'
```

what does this mean?

I'm fairly new to programming so m sorry if the question seems stupid.

Comment: `sizeof(x)` is `sizeof(int*)`, not the size of the array.

Comment: *"How is this justified?"* They are different types (and they don't convert to other).

Comment: It means that a **pointer to an `int`** is not the same as an **`int`**. A pointer represents an address in memory of the computer; you can get an address of an `int` using the `&` operator (it's name is *address-of-operator*): `f2(&a);`. By the way, be aware that `i < sizeof(x)` ain't does what you think it should.

Comment: `void f1(int* begin, int* end)` and call it with `f1(a1, a1+3);` and `f1(&a, &a + 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `f2()` (as well as the `f1()`) waits for a pointer to `int`. While you pass it an `int`, the `a`.

The error `invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'` means that a **pointer to an `int`** is not the same as an **`int`**. A pointer represents **an address in memory** of the computer, an `int` is a variable with integral numeric value, **there's no way** to implicitly convert one to another.

Meanwhile, the `a1` is an array, but when we use the name of an array, it will decay to a pointer to the first element of an array. Check this thread for more: [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay). So you can pass the `a1` to `f1()` without use of the address-of-operator, since the `a1` will decay to a pointer (to `int*`) by itself.

Means that **there is a way** from `int[]` to `int*`.

On the other hand, you can get an address of an `int` (or many other types) using the `&` operator (it's name is *address-of-operator*) like so:

```
f2(&a); // Calls f2() passing it a pointer to a
```

You also need to be aware that `i < sizeof(x)` ain't does what you think it should. The `sizeof(x)` returns the size of `x` in bytes.

You may want to check the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) on the `sizeof()`. And the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) on pointer declaration.

Comment: But then how does it allow array to pass in f1...int* and int array are different right?

Comment: @Orpheus because of the array to pointer decay. In almost all cases, when we use the name of an array, we refer to the pointer to the first element of that array. The `int*` and `int[]` are the same thing in **almost** all of uses (your case is surely one of these). Check the **What is array to pointer decay?** link in the answer for more elaborate information on the array/pointer.

Comment: I was just reading array decays to pointers..cool stuff...I did not know about that.....I could use this method in case or pass an array of the same length....but using a pointer is more viable...thanks a lot @rawrex...and thanks on the headsup about sizeof too

Answer (score 0):

The function f1 accepts only pointer(address) to integer as the input; and below statement is incorrect.

> The function f1 allows me to pass an array as the argument to function but does not allow an integer variable to be passed as an argument.

You are passing the address of the array a1 while you are calling f1(a1). Because a1 is the address of first element of the array a10. However in the next line you are sending an integer with f1(a).